# Mod_proxy redirect http://domain.com/ to http://192.168.1.10/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, mod-proxy

I am trying to use apache2 mod_proxy to redirect `http://domain.com/` to `http://192.168.1.10/wordpress`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/
ProxyPassReverse /wordpress/ http://192.168.1.10/
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit `domain.com` in a web browser I am automatically redirected to `domain.com/wordpress`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/
```

I am almost positive the Reverse calls it and reroutes it.